# UPDATE from SELECT with calculations

Tags: mysql, select, join

I'm trying to do an `UPDATE` from a `SELECT` following the format given by [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2334712/sql-server-update-from-select)

It's not working. I'm wondering if it's because I need a different UPDATE...SELECT structure when performing calculations.

I've tried various versions of the following:

```
        UPDATE tbl_usertime uat
            SET uat.delay_qual = (TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, uat.view_date, '2011-10-11 15:22:25') > adt.delay), 
            freq_qual = (adt.frequency > uat.imps_today)
        FROM tbl_timing adt
        JOIN tbl_usertime uat 
            ON uat.ad_id = adt.ad_id;
```

...but it returns 'error in SQL syntax...near 'FROM tbl_timing adt JOIN tbl_usertime uat'

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: `FROM` is not valid in update queries, only `select` ones.

Comment: @MarcB He's copying from a Sql Server thread and this is valid Sql Server syntax.

Comment: @Icarus: Yes, if the update query contains a select sub-query. OP's code snippet doesn't. `update` queries do not support `from` in any way shape or form, as it's not part of the SQL language spec.

Comment: @MarcB yes they do in SQL Server. Check the answer in the linked post. This doesn't work for the OP because ofcourse the linked post is for SQL Server and he intended to copy/paste in MySQL. Not sure if you can do it, but obviously the syntax is not the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MySQL syntax is a little bit different, try this:

```
update tbl_usertime uat join tbl_timing adt on uat.ad_id=adt.ad_id set
    uat.delay_qual = (TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, uat.view_date, '2011-10-11 15:22:25') > adt.delay), 
        freq_qual = (adt.frequency > uat.imps_today)
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure it will work, but reading MySQL documentation gives me the impression that may be valid:

```
UPDATE tbl_usertime join tbl_timing
SET tbl_usertime.delay_qual = (TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, tbl_usertime.view_date, '2011-10-11 15:22:25') > tbl_timing.delay), 
    freq_qual = (tbl_timing.frequency > tbl_usertime.imps_today)
where 
tbl_usertime.ad_id = tbl_timing.ad_id;
```

Comment: +1 probably works great. was using Xint0's answer when the jon was being fixed.